# Check which string occurs first in a growing file

Tags: linux, bash, logging, grep

I'm running a remote executable which produces a logfile.

I want to write a script to check whether the executable is run successfully or encounters an error. The way I can do this is by looking at the growing log file and seeing if the string `"error"` or `"success"` occurs first.

I know I can grep a file in realtime using

```
tail -f output.log | grep --line-buffered "string"
```

However, can I write a script which will tell me whether the grep for `"error"` or the grep for `"success"` occurs first?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by only looking at the first result returned by `grep`, for example with `head -n1`:

```
status=$(grep -o 'success\|error' output.log | head -n1)
if [[ $status == "success" ]]; then
    # Program started successfully
else
    # Program encountered an error
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need something that will constantly check the file for "success" or "error" and return which one occurs first (in time)

Comment: @Eddy: I know too little about `output.log` to give a better answer. Can you provide more information? For example: How frequently do `error` and `success` occur? Do you have any control over when the program is run?

Answer (score 0):

Search for both strings using grep, extract the line numbers of the first match, and compare the values.

- grep option `-n` gives the line number of any matches.
- option `-m1`
  lists only the first match then exits.
- incidentally option `-F` fast
  grep - may be useful if no regular expressions are required in the
  search string.

An example output from the error grep will look something like - the line number 235 is to be extracted from the output.

```
235:[Wed Jun 04 12:23:19 2014] [error] child pid 6575 Segmentation fault (11)
```

The line numbers can be extracted by deleting the longest substring match `%%:.*` from the  output to leave the numeric values which are compared in the if statement.

```
er_match=$(tail -f output.log | grep -n -F -m1 --line-buffered "error")
ok_match=$(tail -f output.log | grep -n -F -m1 --line-buffered "success")

if [[ ${er_match%%:.*} - gt ${ok_match%%:.*} ]];then
    echo "error first"
else
    echo "sucess first"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **egrep** you can check for either string on each line:

```
egrep 'success|failure'
```

This will bring out the lines in order, and you can pipe the output to something to select the first line.